# Using Nokogiri's swap on text nodes inside a DocumentFragment

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

With Hpricot, you can do this:

```
> doc = Hpricot("a")
=> #<Hpricot::Doc "a">
> doc.children.first.swap('b')
=> ["b"]
> doc.to_s
=> "b"
```

But if you try the same thing with Nokogiri, you get an error:

```
> doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('a')
=> #<Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment:0x825bb88c name="#document-fragment" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x825bb580 "a">]>
> doc.children.first.swap('b')
RuntimeError: error parsing fragment (1)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:509:in `in_context'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:509:in `parse'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/html/document_fragment.rb:22:in `initialize'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:485:in `new'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:485:in `fragment'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:885:in `coerce'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:382:in `replace'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:407:in `swap'
 from (irb):63
```

How can I use `swap` on text nodes in Nokogiri?

**Edit: Note that this isn't a problem with the ARGUMENT to `swap`, it's a problem with the receiver**

For example:

```
> doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('<a>b</a>')
=> #<Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment:0x825bb508 name="#document-fragment" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x825bb1fc name="a" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x825bab6c "b">]>]>
> doc.at("a").swap('x')
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x825bb1fc name="a" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x825bab6c "b">]>
> doc.to_s
=> "x"
```

Comment: Given that almost 100 of your questions answered by individuals donating their free time to help you have not yet been graced by an acceptance mark from you, forgive me if I wait to see how my response to your other question turns out before spending time answering this one.

Comment: My bad dog; I didn't see your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to create a text node that can be used with swap inside a DocumentFragment:

```
require 'nokogiri'    
frag = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse( "foo" )
foo  = frag.children.first
foo.swap( Nokogiri::XML::Text.new( "bar", foo.document ) )
puts frag
#=> bar
```

**Edit:** There's definitely something subtle going on here, based on the following. I've filed a [bug report](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/issues/issue/407) for you. It appears to parse the string correctly if the text is not at the root of the DocumentFragment, or if this is a Document and not fragment:

```
require 'nokogiri'

elems  = "<a1 /><a2>foo</a2><a3 /><a4>bar</a4>baz"
rooted = "<r>#{elems}</r>"
doc = Nokogiri::XML rooted
doc.at_xpath('/r/a1').swap( 'x1' )                  # Element->text
doc.at_xpath('/r/a2/text()').swap( 'jim' )          # Text->text
doc.at_xpath('/r/a3').swap( '<x3 />' )              # Element->element
doc.at_xpath('/r/a4/text()').swap( '<x4>jam</x4>' ) # Text->element
doc.xpath('/r/text()').last.swap( 'jom' )           # RootText->text
puts doc.root
#=> <r>x1<a2>jim</a2><x3/><a4><x4>jam</x4></a4>jom</r>
#=> (correct output)

frag = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse rooted
frag.at_xpath('./r/a1').swap( 'x1' )                  # Element->text
frag.at_xpath('./r/a2/text()').swap( 'jim' )          # Text->text
frag.at_xpath('./r/a3').swap( '<x3 />' )              # Element->element
frag.at_xpath('./r/a4/text()').swap( '<x4>jam</x4>' ) # Text->element
frag.xpath('./r/text()').last.swap( 'jom' )           # RootText->text
puts frag
#=> <r>x1<a2>jim</a2><x3/><a4><x4>jam</x4></a4>jom</r>
#=> (correct output)

frag = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse elems
frag.at_xpath('./a1').swap( 'x1' )                  # Element->text
frag.at_xpath('./a2/text()').swap( 'jim' )          # Text->text
frag.at_xpath('./a3').swap( '<x3 />' )              # Element->element
frag.at_xpath('./a4/text()').swap( '<x4>jam</x4>' ) # Text->element
baz = frag.children.last
begin
  baz.swap( 'jom' )                                 # RootText->text      
rescue Exception => e
  p baz
  #=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80c66224 "baz">

  p e
  #=> #<RuntimeError: error parsing fragment (1)>
  
  puts e.backtrace
  #=> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:509:in `in_context'
  #=> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:509:in `parse'
  #=> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/document_fragment.rb:14:in `initialize'
  #=> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:485:in `new'
  #=> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:485:in `fragment'
  #=> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:885:in `coerce'
  #=> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:382:in `replace'
  #=> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:407:in `swap'
  #=> /Users/phrogz/Desktop/test_swap.rb:32:in `<main>'      
end    
puts frag
#=> x1<a2>jim</a2><x3/><a4>
#=>   <x4>jam</x4>
#=> </a4>baz
```

**Edit 2**: This has been confirmed as a bug by the Nokogiri development team:

> OMG! Thanks for the boog report!
>
> I'm sure we don't have any test coverage that runs Node#replace and #swap on text nodes, so hopefully I'll be able to fix this for the 1.4.5 release.

Comment: @HoraceLoeb Well, see my edit; changing the argument causes it to work. :) I assume the problem is that since you have a document fragment it is not creating a Text node from your markup in the same document. I will edit my answer, though, because you are correct; even trying to swap it with `"<bar />"` fails, so it's not the markup directly that's a problem here.

Comment: Can the anonymous downvoter please explain what about my answer does not both answer the question asked and also shed additional light on the situation?

Comment: Okay, this works, but what if I don't want to insert a Text node? I.e., I want to be able to insert arbitrary markup, like I can with `Hpricot` or `jQuery`. If I use a text node, then `<a>b</a>` will get converted to `&lt;a&gt;b&lt;/a&gt;`. I can use `Nokogiri::XML::Node.new`, but this fails when I just want to insert text.

Comment: @HoraceLoeb See the edit; I've filed a bug for you on this problem.